# How do I distribute weekly average ni data into daily with every days of a week will eventually have its own index .in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file which is as shown as below:

07-31-1995:1.179

08-07-1995:1.174

08-14-1995:1.172

08-21-1995:1.171

08-28-1995:1.163

09-04-1995:1.16

09-11-1995:1.15
09-18-1995:1.157

09-25-1995:1.156

10-02-1995:1.151

10-09-1995:1.14

10-16-1995:1.133

10-23-1995:1.125

This file is named as bill.txt , I want to create a new file which will have data as shown as following:

07-31-1995:1.179

07-01-1995:1.179

07-02-1995:1.179

07-03-1995:1.179

07-04-1995:1.179

07-05-1995:1.179

07-06-1995:1.179

08-07-1995:1.174

08-08-1995:1.174

08-09-1995:1.174

08-10-1995:1.174

08-11-1995:1.174

08-12-1995:1.174

08-13-1995:1.174

08-14-1995:1.172

08-15-1995:1.172

08-16-1995:1.172

08-17-1995:1.172

08-18-1995:1.172

08-19-1995:1.172

08-20-1995:1.172

08-21-1995:1.171

08-22-1995:1.171

.
.
.
I have tried creating a dataframe and using pandas,numpy,_datetime and also .ffill, resample and so on . But i have been getting errors again and again.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('original_dates.txt', header = None)
df.columns = ['original']

# split the date from the trailing number
df[['date', 'number']] = df['original'].str.split(':', expand=True)

# reindex to fill in the missing dates
dates = pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max())
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
reindexed_df = df.reindex(dates)

# reset the index and return the date column to a string
reindexed_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
reindexed_df['date'] = reindexed_df['index'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

# forward fill the missing numbers
reindexed_df['number'] = reindexed_df['number'].ffill()
reindexed_df.drop(['original', 'index'], axis=1)

# join the columns back together
reindexed_df['new_col'] = reindexed_df[['date', 'number']].apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I am getting errors ,unknown stringbformat : Date , could not convert strinh to Timestamp

Comment: Could you post the full error traceback?